# Project Euler Problem 12 - triangle number with 500 divisors

Tags: java, performance, programming-challenge

I've just done Problem 12 of Project Euler:

> What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred divisors?
>
> The \$N\$'th triangle number is the sum of all natural numbers from \$1\$ to \$N\$, for example, the 5th triangle number is \$1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15\$

I get the correct answer in around 2.5 seconds.

I was wondering if anyone could suggest anything that could improve the performance of the program, or improve the code in general.

```
public class Problem12 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    run();
    double endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Took "+((endTime - startTime) / 1000)+" seconds"); 
}

public static void run() {
    boolean go = true;
    long number = 1;
    long nextNum = 2;
    int maxDivisors = 500;
    while (go) {
        if (countDivisors(number) > maxDivisors) {
            System.out.println("The first triangle number with over "+maxDivisors+" divisors is: "+number);
            go = false;
        }
        else {
            number += nextNum;
            nextNum++;
        }
    }
}

public static long countDivisors(long number) {
    long divisors = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i*i <= number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            divisors+=2;
        }
    }
    return divisors;
}
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is an error in your `countDivisors()` function, the result is one too large
for a perfect square, i.e. `countDivisors(25)` returns 4 instead of 3.
Also the loop variable `i` should be a `long` to avoid an integer overflow
when testing `i*i <= number`.
 A correct version would be

```
public static long countDivisors(long number) {
    long divisors = 0;
    for (long i = 1; i*i <= number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            if (i*i < number) {
                divisors += 2; // i and number/i are (different) divisors
            } else {
                divisors += 1; // i == number/i is a divisor
            }
        }
    }
    return divisors;
}
```

The `run()` function can be simplified slightly, the `boolean go` variable
is not really necessary:

```
public static void run() {
    long number = 1;
    long nextNum = 2;
    int maxDivisors = 500;
    while (countDivisors(number) <= maxDivisors) {
        number += nextNum;
        nextNum++;
    }
    System.out.println("The first triangle number with over "+maxDivisors+" divisors is: "+number);
}
```

To improve the performance, use the fact that

- triangle numbers are of the form \$ n \, (n+1)/2  \$, and
- the "number-of-divisors function" \$ \sigma_0(n) \$ is multiplicative,
  i.e. \$ \sigma_0(m \, n) =  \sigma_0(m) \, \sigma_0(n) \$ if \$ m, n \$
  are relative prime (see [Divisor Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function)).

If \$ n \$ is even then \$ n/2 \$ and \$ n+1 \$ are relative prime,
and if \$ n \$  is odd then \$ n \$  and \$ (n+1)/2 \$ are relative prime.
This leads to the following implementation

```
public static void run() {
    long n = 1;
    int maxDivisors = 500;
    while (countDivisors((n+1)/2) * countDivisors(n) <= maxDivisors) {
        n++;
        if (countDivisors(n/2) * countDivisors(n+1) > maxDivisors) {
            break;
        }
        n++;
    }
    long number = n*(n+1)/2;
    System.out.println("The first triangle number with over "+maxDivisors+" divisors is: "+number);
}
```

which is faster because the `countDivisors()` function is called with smaller
numbers. On my computer it reduces the time from 0.6 to 0.02 seconds.

A faster implementation of `countDivisors()` would use the prime
factorisation of the given number, as explained in the above referenced
Wikipedia article.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, with the code you provided it runs in 0.1 seconds which is a huge improvement. I need to get my head around the maths though :).

Comment: You can further optimize the `run()` loop by calling 3 `countDivisors()` out of 4: `for (int n = 1;; n += 2) { int cd = countDivisors((n+1) /2); if (countDivisors(n) * cd > N) { return n * (n + 1) / 2; } if (cd * countDivisors(n + 2) > N) { return (n + 1) * (n + 2) / 2; } }`. And yes, from the solutions presented above, the most efficient one uses prime factorisation.

Answer (score 10):

- Performance.

  ProjectEuler problems are rather about math than programming. To solve problem 12 efficiently you need to learn some number theory facts, specifically the multiplicative property of a number of divisors function \$\sigma(n)\$. You also have to observe that a triangular number is a product of two coprimes. Then you may combine that knowledge into a very efficient algorithm.
- General notes.

  `bool go` is not necessary. When the desired number is found, you can `return`, or `break` the loop, immediately.

  `countDivisors` apparently has a bug: a perfect square counts its root twice.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think you've made me realise I need to look into some more of the math behind these problems.

Answer (score 7):

```
public static long countDivisors(long number) {
    long divisorCount = 0;

    int i = 1;
    while ( i*i < number ) {
        if ( number % i == 0 ) {
            divisorCount += 2;
        }

        i++;
    }

    if ( i*i == number ) {
        divisorCount++;
    }

    return divisorCount;
}
```

Your original version did not check for the possibility that `number` was a perfect square.  The [revised version from Martin R](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/74900/53820) does check, but it does so on every found factor.  We can do better than that.  This version only checks once at the end.  Note:  this may not make an actual performance difference.  The main reason that I like it is that it is clearer about when the check might be done.

I switched from the `for` loop to the `while` to expand the scope of `i`.  This allows us to check it outside the loop.

We do not need to check that `number % i == 0` on that last check, as that will always be true if `number` is `i` squared.  It's enough just to check that the square of `i` is `number`.

```
public static long run(int maxCount) {
    long n = 1;
    while ( countDivisors((n+1)/2) * countDivisors(n) <= maxCount ) {
        n++;
        if ( countDivisors(n/2) * countDivisors(n+1) > maxCount ) {
            break;
        }
        n++;
    }

    return n*(n+1)/2;
}
```

I changed `maxDivisors` to `maxCount` to make it clearer what it is tracking.  The name `maxDivisorCount` would be even clearer but may be overkill.

I changed `maxCount` from a variable declaration to a method parameter.  This makes it easier to change its value if desired.  You can even `run` multiple times with different values now.  This also comes under the category of avoiding magic numbers.  If we're defining a magic number, I'd rather put it in `main` than `run`.

I changed `run` to return a value rather than perform output.  This improves the algorithm timing, as it reduces overhead.  It also makes the function more flexible.  If you wanted to call it and then use the result, you could.  The original version only displayed the result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int maxCount = 500;

    double startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long number = run(maxCount);
    double endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("The first triangle number with more than " + maxCount + " divisors is: " + number);
    System.out.println("Took " + ((endTime - startTime) / 1000) + " seconds"); 
}
```

This is just changed to pass a parameter to `run`, take a return value, and display.