# Project Euler #12 in Swift - Highly divisible triangular number

Tags: programming-challenge, primes, swift

I just finished [Project Euler #12](https://projecteuler.net/problem=12) in Swift, and since there is not any version yet on Code Review, I would like to have some comments on what I did to try to improve it.

> The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural
>   numbers. So the 7th triangle number would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7
>   = 28. The first ten terms would be:
>
> 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...
>
> Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:
>
> 1: 1
>
> 3: 1,3
>
> 6: 1,2,3,6
>
> 10: 1,2,5,10
>
> 15: 1,3,5,15
>
> 21: 1,3,7,21
>
> 28: 1,2,4,7,14,28
>
> We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have
>   over five divisors.
>
> What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five
>   hundred divisors?

```
import Foundation

let OverNumberOfDivisors = 500

extension Int {
    func isMultipleOf(factor: Int) -> Bool {
        return self % factor == 0
    }
}

func findPrimesFactorFrom(let smallest: Int, let toFactor: Int, inout primesFactor:[Int:Int]) {
    var maxFactor = Int(sqrt(Double(toFactor)))
    maxFactor = maxFactor < smallest ? smallest : maxFactor
    for factor in smallest...maxFactor {
        if toFactor.isMultipleOf(factor) {
            primesFactor[factor] = (primesFactor[factor] ?? 0) + 1
            return findPrimesFactorFrom(factor, toFactor / factor, &primesFactor)
        }
    }

    primesFactor[toFactor] = (primesFactor[toFactor] ?? 0) + 1
}

func highlyDivisibleTriangularNumber() -> Int {

    var currentNumberOfDivisors = 1
    var triangleNumber = 1
    var number = 1

    var primesFactor:[Int:Int] = [:]

    while OverNumberOfDivisors >= currentNumberOfDivisors {

        number++
        triangleNumber += number
        primesFactor = [:]

        findPrimesFactorFrom(2, triangleNumber, &primesFactor)

        currentNumberOfDivisors = 1
        for (index, factor) in primesFactor {
            if index != 1 {
                currentNumberOfDivisors *= (factor + 1)
            }
        }
    }

    return triangleNumber
}

func euler12() {
    let number = highlyDivisibleTriangularNumber()

    println(number)
}

func printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(operation:() -> ()) {
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    operation()
    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    println("Time elapsed : \(timeElapsed) s")
}

printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(euler12)
```

The code executes in 0.3s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the required number of divisors (500 + 1) a parameter of the 
function, and move the computation of the number of divisors into a separate
function:

```
func highlyDivisibleTriangularNumber(requiredDivisors : Int) -> Int {

    var triangleNumber = 0
    var number = 0
    var currentNumberOfDivisors : Int

    do {
        number++
        triangleNumber += number
        currentNumberOfDivisors = countDivisors(triangleNumber)
    } while currentNumberOfDivisors < requiredDivisors

    return triangleNumber
}

func euler12() {
    let number = highlyDivisibleTriangularNumber(500 + 1)
    println(number)
}
```

Counting the number of divisors is done via the prime factorization (which is good). Your prime factorization is done recursively and returns a dictionary
of factor/exponent pairs. I would prefer an iterative algorithm:

```
func primeFactorization(var n : Int) -> [Int : Int] {
    var factors : [Int : Int] = [:]
    var factor = 2

    while factor * factor <= n {
        if n % factor == 0 {
            var exponent = 0
            do {
                exponent++
                n /= factor
            } while n % factor == 0
            factors[factor] = exponent
        }
        factor = factor == 2 ? 3 : factor + 2
    }
    if n > 1 {
        factors[n] = 1
    }

    return factors
}
```

I prefer the explicit `if n % factor == 0` instead of `if n.isMultipleOf(factor)`
with a custom extension, but that might be a matter of taste.

This gives only a small performance improvement, but the function does
now *return* the factorization, so you don't have to pass an `inout` argument.

Also the result cannot contain the factor 1 (as in your method). So counting the number of divisors would simply be

```
func countDivisors(num : Int) -> Int {

    var numDivisors = 1
    for (prime, exponent) in primeFactorization(num) {
        numDivisors *= (exponent + 1)
    }
    return numDivisors
}
```

The variable names `(prime, exponent)` might be more descriptive
than `(index, factor)` in your code. As the prime number (the dictionary key)
is not needed in the loop you can also write

```
for (_, exponent) in primeFactorization(num) {
    numDivisors *= (exponent + 1)
}
```

or just

```
for exponent in primeFactorization(num).values {
    numDivisors *= (exponent + 1)
}
```

But actually it is more efficient to combine the prime factorization and
the computation of the number of divisors into a single method, without
storing the factors and exponents in an intermediate dictionary:

```
func countDivisors(var n : Int) -> Int {

    var numDivisors = 1
    var factor = 2

    while factor * factor <= n {
        if n % factor == 0 {
            var exponent = 0
            do {
                exponent++
                n /= factor
            } while n % factor == 0
            numDivisors *= exponent + 1
        }
        factor = factor == 2 ? 3 : factor + 2
    }
    if n > 1 {
        numDivisors *= 2
    }

    return numDivisors
}
```

and this is much faster (0.02 instead of 0.14 seconds).

The most performance improvement can be gained by taking advantage of the
special form `n * (n+1)/2` of the triangle numbers, and this are the same
arguments as in

- [Project Euler Problem 12 - triangle number with 500 divisors](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74895/project-euler-problem-12-triangle-number-with-500-divisors)

In Swift this would be

```
func highlyDivisibleTriangularNumber(requiredDivisors : Int) -> Int {

    var n = 1
    while (countDivisors((n+1)/2) * countDivisors(n) < requiredDivisors) {
        n++;
        if (countDivisors(n/2) * countDivisors(n+1) >= requiredDivisors) {
            break;
        }
        n++;
    }
    let triangleNumber = n*(n+1)/2
    return triangleNumber
}
```

which runs in 0.006 seconds on my computer.

Comment: It is more efficient to combine the prime factorization and the computation of the number of divisors into a single method. Thanks!