# Getting the divisors count of an integer

Tags: javascript

I am using mod and my code works.  I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to write a method that returns the total number of divisors for an integer.

```
function getDivisorsCnt(n){
    var divisors = 0;
    mod = n;
    while (mod > 0){
      if(n % mod === 0){
        divisors++;
      }
      mod--;
    }
    return divisors;
}
```

Comment: As always, you can play the speed/memory trade-off and a use a (huge?) pre-computed array of primes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some general remarks:

- Variables should be declared explicitly with `var`, otherwise you
  create a global variable.
- The indent amount is different between the first level and the
  deeper levels.
- The spacing is not consistent: `while (` vs `if(`. Generally I would
  insert a space at least after keywords, and around parentheses/braces etc.

Your implementation is correct but not efficient, as the number of loop iterations
and remainder operations is equal to the input number.

The count of divisors can be efficiently computed from the 
prime number factorization: If
$$
 n = p_1^{e_1} \, p_2^{e_2} \cdots p_k^{e_k}
$$
is the factorization of \$ n \$ into prime numbers \$ p_i \$
with exponents \$ e_i \$, then 
$$
 \sigma_0(n) = (e_1+1)(e_2+1) \cdots (e_k+1)
$$
is the number of divisors of \$ n \$, see for example
[Wikipedia: Divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function). Example:
$$
 720 = 2^4 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^1 \Longrightarrow
  \sigma_0(720) = (4+1)(2+1)(1+1) = 30 \, .
$$

An implementation in JavaScript would be

```
function getDivisorsCnt(n){

    var numDivisors = 1;
    var factor = 2; // Candidate for prime factor of `n`

    // If `n` is not a prime number then it must have one factor
    // which is <= `sqrt(n)`, so we try these first:
    while (factor * factor <= n) {
        if (n % factor === 0) {
            // `factor` is a prime factor of `n`, determine the exponent:
            var exponent = 0;
            do {
                n /= factor;
                exponent++;
            } while (n % factor === 0)
            // `factor^exponent` is one term in the prime factorization of n,
            // this contributes as factor `exponent + 1`:
            numDivisors *= exponent + 1;
        }
        // Next possible prime factor:
        factor = factor == 2 ? 3 : factor + 2
    }

    // Now `n` is either 1 or a prime number. In the latter case,
    // it contributes a factor 2:
    if (n > 1) {
        numDivisors *= 2;
    }

    return numDivisors;
}
```

As an example, `getDivisorsCnt(720)` requires 720 remainder operations
in your algorithm, but only 8 remainder operations and 6 divisions in this algorithm.

Comment: At each iteration, you have to calculate factor², wouldn't it be faster to compare factor with √n (calculated only once)?

Comment: @Yukulélé: No, because n *decreases* in each loop iteration.

Comment: Since all primes above 3 are of the form `6n±1` can we improve with something like

`factor += (k = !k) ? 2 : 4`?

Answer (score 4):

There definitely is a more efficient way to count a value's divisors.

We know that a number's square root multiplied by itself is the largest possible divisor besides itself, so we cut the number of divisors we check in half.

```
function getDivisorsCount(n) {
    // 1 is a special case where "1 and itself" are only one divisor rather than 2
    if (n === 1) {
        return 1;
    }

    var divisors = 2; // acounts for "1 and itself"

    var mod = 2;
    while (mod * mod <= n) {
        if (n % mod === 0) {
            if (mod * mod < number) {
                // mod and number/mod are (different) divisors
                divisors += 2;
            } 
            else {
                // mod == number/mod is a divisor
                divisors += 1; 
            }
        }
        mod++;
    }

    return divisors;
}
```

As a note, zero and negative numbers are probably also special cases that aren't necessarily handled correctly here.

Comment: I think this it not entirely correct. In your loop, each divisor `mod` has to be counted *twice* (because both `mod` and `n/mod` are a divisor of `n`), *unless* `mod*mod == n`. A Java implementation of that method is (for example) here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/74900/35991.

Comment: 10 has the divisors 1, 2, 5, 10. You initialize divisors with 2 (for 1 and 10). Then mod runs from 2 to 3, and divisors is incremented by one (when mod==2), giving the (incorrect) result 3. Or did I overlook something?

Comment: You're right.  I see it now.  Now I kind of wonder what would be more efficient... this approach, or leaving my original loop body and changing the conditional to `while (mod * 2 <= n)` (and it might depend on which number is passed in).

Comment: Wouldn't it better to write that `while` loop as a `for` loop? `for(var mod = 2; mod*mod <= n; mod++) {`

Comment: Maybe. I don't really know JavaScript... This is more of an algorithm answer...