# Beginner's attempt for Project Euler problem 12 (highly divisible triangle number)

Tags: python, beginner, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I'm a couple weeks into learning Python and I'm working through the Project Euler problems. [Problem 12 asks](https://projecteuler.net/problem=12):

> What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred divisors?

My problem is that my code takes far too long.

I had a list in there to store the factors but I replaced it with a counter variable to count the number of factors. It resets after looping through the divisors.

I'm not entirely sure but I feel like there is a much better way to cycle through the divisors?

How could I optimise this piece of code?

```
target = 100000000

counter = 0


for value in xrange(1, target + 1):
    x = (value * (value + 1))/2
    for divisor in xrange(1, x+1):
        product = x % divisor
        if product == 0:
            counter += 1

    if counter >= 500:
        print x
        sys.exit()

    else:
        counter = 0
```

I appreciate that similar questions have already been asked but I am hoping to gain useful 'personalised' advice from this community

Please excuse the vague variable names and the code in general...

Comment: See [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74895/project-euler-problem-12-triangle-number-with-500-divisors/74901#74901)

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Iteration, flow control, naming, and clarity

Your iteration is a bit clumsy.

It seems that `target` is an arbitrarily chosen number that you picked just to act as a sufficiently large second parameter to `xrange()`.  If you want an unbounded counting loop, [`itertools.count(1)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) would be better.

Instead of `else: counter = 0`, you should just set `counter = 0` in the right place — just before the inner loop.

Avoid using `sys.exit()` — it's like killing your program with a sledgehammer.  You should structure your code so that it terminates naturally.

```
from itertools import count

for value in count(1):
    x = (value * (value + 1))/2
    for divisor in xrange(1, x+1):
        product = x % divisor
        if product == 0:
            counter += 1

    if counter >= 500:
        break

print x
```

There is an idiom for counting items that meet some criterion: [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).

```
from itertools import count

for value in count(1):
    x = (value * (value + 1)) / 2
    if 500 <= sum(1 for divisor in xrange(1, x + 1) if x % divisor == 0):
        print x
        break
```

As you noted yourself, your variables are poorly named.  `product`, in particular, should be called `remainder`.  `counter` is vague; `divisor_count` would be more helpful.

What you want to express is a loop over the triangle numbers.  For even greater clarity, I'd break that out into a triangle number generator function.

```
from itertools import count

def triangle_numbers():
    """Generator of triangle numbers, starting with 1, 1+2, 1+2+3, ..."""
    n = 0
    for i in count(1):
        n += i
        yield n

def divisor_count(n):
    """Count of the divisors of n"""
    return sum(1 for divisor in xrange(1, n + 1) if n % divisor == 0)

print next(t for t in triangle_numbers() if divisor_count(t) >= 500)
```

### Mathematics

Note that \$\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\$ is a product of two coprimes.  As explained [here](/a/60293/9357), the divisors of such a product can be computed based on the divisors of each of its two known factors.

```
from itertools import count

def divisor_count(n):
    """Count of the divisors of n"""
    return sum(1 for divisor in xrange(1, n + 1) if n % divisor == 0)

for n in count(1):
    tn = n * (n + 1) // 2
    # n and (n + 1) are relatively prime.  Therefore, if n is even,
    # the factors of tn can be derived from the factors of n/2 and
    # the factors of n+1. If n is odd, then the factors of tn can be
    # derived from the factors of n and the factors of ((n+1)/2).
    tn_divisor_count = (
        divisor_count(n // 2) * divisor_count(n + 1) if n % 2 == 0 else
        divisor_count(n) * divisor_count((n + 1) // 2)
    )
    if tn_divisor_count >= 500:
        print tn
        break
```

Comment: Good answer, but for a beginner, a generator function might be a bit much.